# GraphQL large integer error: Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I´m trying to store a UNIX timestamp in `MongoDB` using `GraphQL`, but it seens that GraphQL has a limit to handle integers. See the mutation below:

```
const addUser = {
    type: UserType,
    description: 'Add an user',
    args: {
        data: {
            name: 'data',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(CompanyInputType)
        }
    },
    resolve(root, params) {

        params.data.creationTimestamp = Date.now();

        const model = new UserModel(params.data);
        const saved = model.save();

        if (!saved)
            throw new Error('Error adding user');

        return saved;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: 1499484833027",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 14,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "addUser",
        "creationTimestamp"
      ]
    }
```

I´m currently using `GraphQLInteger` for this field on type definition:

```
creationTimestamp: { 
    type: GraphQLInt
}
```

How can I solve that situation if there is no larger `GraphQLInt` available in `GraphQL` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't support integers larger than 32 bits as the error indicates. You're better off using a custom scalar like [GraphQL Date](https://github.com/tjmehta/graphql-date). There's also a "Long" type available [here](https://github.com/chadlieberman/graphql-type-long). Or you could roll your own custom type; there's a great example from Apollo [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/scalars.html#Own-GraphQLScalarType-instance).

If you're curious why GraphQL does not support anything bigger, you can check out [this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/73).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Could we get an explanation?  :D

Comment: @reergymerej what is still unclear from the answer?

Comment: I think what @reergymerej meant is a TLDR for why GraphQL doesn't support integers larger than 32 bits.

Comment: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/292#issuecomment-186702763

Answer (score 8):

**⚠️Not recommended due to potential loss of precision...**

... but if you want a quick fix (maybe you don't have the time to implement a custom scalar), you can use the `Float` type instead of `Int`.

Comment: Hey, I downvoted your comment because it's not very helpful and you're even "Not recommending" it, yourself. Float and Int share the same bit-size.

Comment: I mean I know but when I came to this error I didn't had the time at all to refactorise all my schema like mentioned in the valid answer :/ this error is kind of unexpected since simple timestamp doesn't fit in (and please try it by your own because this 'trick' works I found it in [this issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1003)). So yes maybe it's not the best answer but it could definitively help someone which faced the same problem so there is no reason to downvote it.

Comment: This says not recommended, but does not provide a reason why you wouldn't want to do this.

Comment: @Gakio Because it's better to use the right type for what you need. If you don't need to use some floats there is no point.

Comment: The real issue is that a signed 32 bit integer can exactly represent any integer up to about 2 x 10^9. A 32 bit float can exactly represent any integer up to about 1.5 x 10^7 but can **approximately** represent numbers up to about 3 x 10^38: a hugely wider range but at the cost of precision. 

Sometimes loss of precision is fine and other times it very isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`Float` instead of `Int` is actually not a bad choice in some cases. `Int` is a 32-bit integer, which means that it can safely represent numbers with up to 9 decimal digits, whereas `Float` is a **64-bit** floating-point number (see: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/), which means it has 53 significant bits, which then translates to safely representing all integers with up to 15 decimal digits.